# Can i restrict users from copying the button link on my website?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am working on React and Django Rest Framework with AWS. I don't have Public Access blocked on AWS. I am running short on time as I have to complete my project. I want users who access my website to not be able to right-click and copy the download button link. Because then they can save it and share it.

Any suggestions? I was wondering if I could disable the copy link address for the download button. That would make things much easier for me.

code snippet illustrating how to disable the copy link address for a button

Comment: Its not possible to do that. Any one who really wants, will be able to copy the link.

Comment: Welcome to the Internet. Anything your browser can access can be saved. Why do you want them to be able to access something but not save it?

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach here is to generate an expiring link to the S3 object. Give it a short expiration time - a couple of minutes, or even less if you only generate it when the user only clicks the link - and sharing it around thus won't be all that useful.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

In Python, you can use Boto to do this. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_name}, ExpiresIn=300)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable right click using this

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    });
}, [ ])
```